# Add string values to variable depending on another variable

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

I have the following variable in bash:
$httpd_server_count, this variable can contain values like 1 or 2 and etc. And depending on this value I need to get proper value in $settings variable. The string is:

If the $httpd_server_count=1:

```
settings={'httpd1': {'server': 'settings.server1'},
```

If the $httpd_server_count=2:

```
settings={'httpd1': {'server': 'settings.server1'}, {'httpd2': {'server': 'settings.server2'},
```

and count can be is up to 10 and more. How to properly organize it in code?

Comment: _How to properly organize it in code_ What is wrong with this and why do you want a new one?

Comment: the main reason I don't want to duplicate the code, if the max count is 50 then it will be very big if statement.

Comment: Could you please show an example how it would be with an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a bit unclear on what you are needing, but it appears you want to read the value of `httpd_server_count` and based on the number `1, 2, whatever` generate the server strings needed. If I have it right, one way would be to use a simple C-Style `for` loop based on `httpd_server_count`. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

str=
for ((i = 1; i <= $httpd_server_count; i++)); do
    str="${str}{'httpd$i': {'server': 'settings.server$i'}, "
done

echo -e "str\n\n$str"
```

You would still be responsible for trimming the trailing `,` and appending a closing `'}'` if required. But, if your value of `httpd_server_count` is `1`, then you get:

```
{'httpd1': {'server': 'settings.server1'},
```

If it is `2`, you get:

```
{'httpd1': {'server': 'settings.server1'}, {'httpd2': {'server': 'settings.server2'},
```

This may give you an idea you can run with. Let me know if you have any questions. (by the way, a json parser is generally preferred, like `jq`)

Comment: `++` would have done the same way! Not posting it as a separate one. BTW using an array would slightly look neater. But a proper `JSON` tool would be the ideal way.

Answer (score 3):

Use *functions* in `bash` to make the code more portable and efficient. Just put the code in a wrapper like below. Logic is similar to this [David C. Rankin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41544467/5291015),

```
function settingsGenerator() {   
    local httpd_server_count=$1

    local i
    local settings

    for ((i=1; i<=httpd_server_count; i++))
    do
        settings="${settings}{'httpd$i': {'server': 'settings.server$i'}, "
    done

    printf "%s" "$settings"
}
```

and store the output of the function in a variable, `settings` as

```
settings=$(settingsGenerator 2)
printf "%s\n" "$settings"
{'httpd1': {'server': 'settings.server1'},{'httpd2': {'server': 'settings.server2'},
```

Using arrays would require a small change something like,

```
function settingsGenerator() {   
    local httpd_server_count=$1

    local i
    local settings=()

    for ((i=1; i<=httpd_server_count; i++))
    do
        settings+="{httpd$i': {'server': 'settings.server$i'}, "
    done

    printf "%s" "${settings[@]}"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use for loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq $httpd_server_count`; do
    settings+="{'httpd$i': {'server': 'settings.server$i'}, "
done
```

Comment: No, it is also working for strings. man bash: `In the context where an assignment statement is assigning a value to  a
       shell variable or array index, the += operator can be used to append to
       or add to the variable's previous value.  This  includes  arguments  to
       builtin  commands  such  as  declare  that accept assignment statements
       (declaration commands).  [...]
When  +=  is  applied  to an array variable[...]`